Launchctl plist with StartCalendarInterval not executing
I have a plist which runs a script and if I launch it using StartInterval it runs the script but if I use StartCalendarInterval it doesn't run the script.
Further details are:

The plist is below and it's located in my ~/library/launchagents folder.
my test script simply runs 'date >> /tmp/date.txt'
MacOS is Sonoma 14.5

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.test.copytosynctest_startCal</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/test/sync/_automationscripts/copytosynctest.zsh</string>
  </array>
<key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
  <key>Minute</key>
  <integer>52</integer>
  <key>Hour</key>
  <integer>13</integer>
</dict>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <false/>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosynctest1.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosynctest1.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>

This is the same plist but using StartInterval instead of StartCalendarInterval and this works fine.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.test.copytosynctest</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/test/sync/_automationscripts/copytosynctest.zsh</string>
  </array>
<key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>60</integer>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosynctest1.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosynctest1.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>


It shouldn't matter, but try putting the Hour key before the Minute key. Also, take out the RunAtLoad key, which is unnecessary and not recommended in the man page launchd.plist(5). See if that makes any difference. You know, of course, that the job won't start until the next login unless you load it manually with launchctl.

I've made the changes you mentioned but no better. I forgot to mention I'm loading and unloading manually for testing.

You say you have a different version of the job that works. Please post that.

You could save yourself time and frustration by getting a copy of LaunchControl. It's one of the few 3rd party Mac apps I use; excellent IMHO.

I have the trial of LaunchControl and it confirms the plist is valid. It just doesn't work.

I've added the version using StartInterval above.

Doesn't StartCalendarInterval need weekday params?

Not according to the doco. It defaults to Any Day if nothing is specified.
Interestingly/strangely, I asked chatgpt to create a plist and it basically created the same as I have but included StartInterval at 86400 AND StartCalendarInterval at the time I specified....but it still didn't work. If I reduce the StartInterval to 60secs then it runs on that cycle.
I can probably use this as a workaround since I only want to run this script daily, so I calculate how many seconds that is, but this doesn't allow me to specify a TOD.

Does launchd write anything to the log when the job is scheduled to run? I don't mean the output from the script, but from launchd itself.

OK. So I've found out what the problem is but it raises another question. When I load the plist with a StartCalendarInterval time of 09:30 (for example), LaunchControl shows the start time as 09:30 but the log entry shows a start time of 11:30 (2 hours later). Now, I'm in east coast Australia (AEST timezone) so the timezone may be an issue but why is it specifically 2 hours later and how do I make the scheduled time correct?

FYI, I tried adding my specific timezone to the plist but it's still schedules 2 hours later

This sounds like a bug. You could try adding the LegacyTimers key with a value of True.

Thanks for the suggestion but I just tried that and it had no effect. I'll just subtract 2 hours from my StartCalendarInterval time to execute at my preferred run time.

@webby: Just curious: What did you do to make your job start?

Not clear what you're referring too but my first posted plist using StartCalendarInterval always started but 2 hours later than specified for reasons unknown.

I'm referring to your comment from Jun 22 ar 1:15:
OK. So I've found out what the problem is… Your question is about the job not starting at all but this has been solved somehow. I'd just like to learn how. About the time deviation: Is the job really started two hours late or is it only the output of the date command? An easy way to find out is to configure the job to start one minute from the time of loading it and wait if it actually does something. If it does then your TZ environment variable might be not set correctly which makes date output an unexpected timestamp.

So, the problem I observed was that the job wasn't starting at the time I specified in my plist. When I eventually looked at the log I found it was being scheduled for two hours later so it would have started then. My workaround was to specify a start time two hours earlier in the plist. The issue has nothing to do with the time zone which was correct (the log showed this) and the initial problem causing the two hour scheduling delay is unresolved/unknown.
